# ¿Como evitar que lance error al tratar de crear una carpeta en google drive?

Tags: java, android, google-drive

Lo que ocurre es que quiero crear una carpeta en google drive mi código perfecto, el problema que al usarlo y no se si es porque no tiene buena conexión de Internet o son los servicios de google que todavía no a enlazado la cuenta con la api de google drive.

El código es fácil solicita la aceptación de  servicios y luego crea una carpeta.

El fin lo que quiero es encontrar una manera de evitar este error que causa un colapse en la aplicación haciendo que se produzca el famoso error "La aplicación se a detenido".

El código de creación de carpeta es:

```
        MetadataChangeSet changeSet =
        new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
            .setTitle(foldername)
            .build();

    //Opción 1: Directorio raíz
    DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(apiClient);

    //Opción 2: Otra carpeta distinta al directorio raiz
    //DriveFolder folder =
    //        DriveId.decodeFromString("DriveId:CAESABjKGSD6wKnM7lQoAQ==").asDriveFolder();

    folder.createFolder(apiClient, changeSet).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult result) {
                   if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                       Log.i("LOGTAG", "Fichero creado con ID = " + result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId());
                       SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("ID", result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId().toString());
                        editor.commit();

                   } else {
                       Log.e("LOGTAG", "Error al crear el fichero");
                   }
            }
        });
```

Y El código de registro es:

```
 GoogleApiClient apiClient;
         apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this,0, this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
        .build();
```

Actualmente trato de resolver este error colocando un onConnectionFailed que avisa con un toast al usuario y comienza de nuevo el sistema de registro. Pero no ocurre nada.

```
    @Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error de conexion!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ocurrio un Error volver a registrase por favor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Verificar conexion a internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this,0, this)
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
    .build();

}
```

Si conoce como solucionar este tema. Estaré feliz de escucharle. Gracias.

Comment: Tendras algo del log del error que lanza??

Comment: En ningún momento veo que te conectas al `apiClient` que estás creando. ¿Has seguido las indicaciones explicadas aquí (https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth?),  particularmente donde dice: _After you create the client, you must connect it for authorization to occur._?

Answer (score 0):

Engloba tu código en

```
try
{

}
catch (Exception error)
{

}
```

En el try colocas tu código y en el catch lo que quieres que haga en caso de error.

Usa debug para saber qué error tienes y poder tratarlo mejor, es una recomendación.